# Access i18next Translation in Function not in App.js

Tags: node.js, express, i18next

Im using ExpressJS and i18next.

in `app.js`

```
var express = require('express')
  , i18n = require('i18next')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
...
//internationalization
i18n.init({
  lng: 'en-US',
  saveMissing: true,
  debug: true
});
...  
app.use(i18n.handle);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
...
i18n.registerAppHelper(app);
...
app.post('/users/save', user.save);
```

I can access the translation in jade:

```
t('app.title')
```

How can I access the translation in `routes.user.js`

```
exports.save = function(req, res){
    //t('app.title')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`t` is available in your route handlers as `res.locals.t`. This should work in Express 3 and 2 as well.

Answer (score 0):

[i18next-express-middleware](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-express-middleware#wire-up-i18next-to-request-object) -> the translation function could be accessed through `req.i18n.t` or just `req.t`. but obviously it's under `res.locals.t` too - to be accessible in templates.